# Android BottomSheetDialog with EditText covered by keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

[edittext covered by keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mRmr.png)

Here is my dialog layout content. When the button on the screen clicked, this dialog will be shown, and covered by the keyboard. How to solve this problem ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:layout_width="400dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are opening keyboard on button click or EditText click??

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50948146/7958563

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your class:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

The above line of code will push your layout up to make the EditText visible when it has focus & keyboard is seen.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, add a new style can solve this problem

1. Step1:Add style

```
<style name="BottomSheetStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

2. Step 2:Use the style

```
// method 1
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context, R.style.BottomSheetStyle);
// or method 2 
super(context, R.style.BottomSheetStyle);
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
 public void show_Messgae() {

    final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Window window = mDialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.WHITE));

  //diaog is the name of ur layout
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    mDialog.setCancelable(false);

    EditText et_name=(EditText)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.et_name);

    //to show keyboard
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

    mDialog.show();



}
```