# Keyboard hides BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

There are more fields below the keyboard. This happened when i updated the support library. I know it's Kotlin but it looks almost the same as java. How do I fix this issue?

This is what it looks like:

[image]

My code:

```
class ProjectsEditBottomSheetFragment(val privateID: String,
                                  val publicID: String) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {



private val mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
            dismiss()
        }

    }


    override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
        if (slideOffset < -0.15f) {
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}


override fun setupDialog(dialog: Dialog, style: Int) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style)
    val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.projects_edit_sheet, null)
    dialog.setContentView(view)

    dialog.window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)


    val params = (view.parent as View).layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
    val behavior = params.behavior

    if (behavior != null && behavior is BottomSheetBehavior<*>) {
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback)
    }


    // Get and set values
    val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    val realmObject = realm.where(ProjectsRealmObject::class.java)
            .equalTo("privateID", privateID)
            .findFirst()




    realm.beginTransaction()
    view.title_input.text = SpannableStringBuilder(realmObject.title)
    view.description_input.text = SpannableStringBuilder(realmObject.description)
    view.public_checkbox.isChecked = realmObject.isPublic
    realm.commitTransaction()


    // Keyboard
    view.title_input.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            (context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager).showSoftInput(view.title_input, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED)
        } else {
            (context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager).hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.title_input.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }

    view.description_input.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            (context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager).showSoftInput(view.description_input, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED)
        } else {
            (context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager).hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.description_input.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }


    // Click listners
    view.public_layout.setOnClickListener { view.public_checkbox.toggle() }

    view.cancel.setOnClickListener {
        view?.hideKeyboard()
        dismiss()
    }

    view.save.setOnClickListener {
        view?.hideKeyboard()
        // Save to realm
        realm.beginTransaction()
        realmObject.title = if (view.title_input.text.toString() == "") getString(R.string.unnamed) else view.title_input.text.toString()
        realmObject.description = view.description_input.text.toString()
        realmObject.isPublic = view.public_checkbox.isChecked
        realmObject.synced = false
        realmObject.updatedRealm = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString() + ""
        realm.commitTransaction()

        ProjectsSync(context)

        toast("Sparat")

        dismiss()
    }

  }
}
```

xml:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
app:layout_collapseMode="none"
app:behavior_hideable="false"
app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
style="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/edit_info_placeholder_title"
                android:id="@+id/title_input"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/edit_info_placeholder_description"
                android:id="@+id/description_input"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/click"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/public_layout">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/public_checkbox"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/edit_info_placeholder_is_public"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                style="@style/textMedium"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Buttons -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/edit_info_button_cancel"
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/edit_info_button_save"
                android:id="@+id/save"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: kotlin code is fine. please post your styles.xml code.

Comment: what version of android design library do you use? It works just fine in 25.3.1, but don't work in 25.4.0

Comment: any updates about this?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I found the solution for 27 api. So the reason why keyboard hides view even with SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE is that the windowIsFloating is set for Dialogs.

The most convenient way that I found to change this is by creating style:

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

And set this in `onCreate` method of your `BottomSheetDialogFragment`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle)
}
```

This is how it looks on my device:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! Also note that it's important that the top layout is a ScrollView, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: @headsvk actually it does not matter what is the top layout. On screenshoot I have simple ConstraintLayout with EditText and TextView. BottomSheetDialogFragment wraps my layout in necessary layout.

Comment: @jblejder Maybe your layout is simple enough that you don't need it. I had more TextViews and buttons below the edit text and I had to wrap ConstraintLayout with a ScrollView otherwise it didn't work properly.

Comment: For me it only worked with `android:isScrollContainer="true"` on the child view that should be scrollable.

Comment: `android:statusBarColor` requires API 21 and why is it needed?

Comment: this works, i had parent ConstraintLayout with complex design, works only when i wrapped ConstraintLayout with NestedScrollView (ScrollView is not working)

Comment: @jblejder I am using Constraint Layout and tried your solution but it did not work,can you add your XML code too?

Comment: @CoolMind `android:statusBarColor` is not necessary but without it, with other settings default, there will be status bar visible that breaks BottomSheetDialog feeling.

@Shruti I just tried my solution once again and seems to be working fine even with ConstraintLayout. Just make sure you have all vertical constraint set.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56631966/5064151

Comment: If you don't want to set style to all your BottomSheetDialogFragments, you can define default style for app theme:
```<style name="YOURTHEME" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! Only worked when NestedScrollView was parent container.

Comment: to be more specified on the `NestedScrollView` it's not required in my case I've to extend only `BottomSheetDialogFragment` instead of the library I'm using and of course, the styling step is too important :D

Comment: @headsvk after around 4 hours of trying, finally i saw your comment and it's done, Thank You!!

Answer (score 24):

I tried all of answers in this topic but nothing helped. I looked through many sites and found only one solution that working for me.

```
 override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

    dialog.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
    dialog.setOnShowListener {
        Handler().post {
            val bottomSheet = (dialog as? BottomSheetDialog)?.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as? FrameLayout
            bottomSheet?.let {
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(it).state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            }
        }
    }

    return dialog
}
```

[Original solution](https://lepiolet.fr/2017/09/25/bottomsheetdialogfragment-et-keyboard/)

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Comment: May I know what is `R.id.design_bottom_sheet`?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng this is `FrameLayout` from `com.google.android.material`. If you can't find that id in the `R` class just use `com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the next class:

```
import android.graphics.Rect; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class TestBottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragmentView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false);
        if (getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
           getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        }
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
            decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
                Rect displayFrame = new Rect();
                decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayFrame);
                int height = decorView.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
                int heightDifference = height - displayFrame.bottom;
                if (heightDifference != 0) {
                    if (fragmentView.getPaddingBottom() != heightDifference) {
                        fragmentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, heightDifference);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (fragmentView.getPaddingBottom() != 0) {
                        fragmentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        getDialog().setOnShowListener(dialog -> {
            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
            View bottomSheetInternal = d.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            if (bottomSheetInternal == null) return;
             BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetInternal).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        });
        return fragmentView;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should give some explanation on your answer

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me

```
public class CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment 
{
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
    savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_dialog_bottom_sheet, container, false);


getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    return v;
 }
```

Comment: May be. I didn't check on 27. Please put your working code for android 27 if you find

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the highest score is partly right. In my case, 90% of the view is visible after the same style is set. Finally, I made it completely visible through the following solution:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus) {
                (this@****BottomSheetDialogFragment.dialog as BottomSheetDialog).behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me after spending 5 hours without luck:

## Step #1:

Add this code to your styles.xml (located in res\values folder)

```
<style name="CustomizedBottomDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.7</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

The key here is to set **android:windowIsFloating** -> **false**, if it is **true** your code will not work! Therefor i used rather  **android:backgroundDimEnabled** and **android:backgroundDimAmount** to make background looks transparent with beautiful overlay.

## Step #2:

Write this function to adjust it programmatically (note it is not optional, you need to perform both steps #1 and #2):

```
private fun showDialog() {

    BottomSheetDialog(requireActivity(), R.style.CustomizedBottomDialogStyle).apply {

        window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)

        setOnShowListener {
            Handler().post {
                val bottomSheet = findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as? FrameLayout
                bottomSheet?.let {
                    BottomSheetBehavior.from(it).state = STATE_EXPANDED
                }
            }
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout)

        // Your code goes here....

        show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions posted are changing the theme of `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

However, this has a side effect, of "not smooth" keyboard animation.

My suggestion is to use

```
setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
```

The complete source code is as follow

```
import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.WindowManager
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment
import com.yocto.wetodo.databinding.TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding

class TodoInputDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private var _binding: TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        return root
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

        dialog.window?.also {
            it.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
        }

        return dialog
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

### Output (Smooth keyboard animation)

[image]

---

But, there are 2 glitches which I do not have a solution yet.

### How should we resolve deprecated `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE`?

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` is deprecated. Based https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE, we should use `Window#setDecorFitsSystemWindows(boolean)`. But, it isn't clear how we should apply `Window#setDecorFitsSystemWindows(boolean)` for the above case.

---

### Smooth keyboard animation will gone if we are applying style?

If I want to apply theme on the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, I will lost the smooth keyboard animation.

For instance, I add the following code

### TodoInputDialogFragment.kt

```
class TodoInputDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.TodoInputDialogFragment)
    }
    ...
```

### styles.xml

```
<style name="TodoInputDialogFragment" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

### Output (No more smooth keyboard animation)

[image]

If you know how to resolve such glitches, leave your comment below :) Thank you

Answer (score -1):

add this to your styles

```
<style name="DialogStyle">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

then in your's bottom sheet dialog's onCreate() add

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.DialogStyle);
```

also don't forget to add to dialog's setupDialog() method

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: It worked now. I have posted the code separately which is working for me. Thanks for your suggestion, will try that as well.