# How to make layout slide up from bottom?

Tags: android

Click the button to get LinearLayout from the bottom.
But there's a problem.

1. After the layout is finished, the VideoView doesn't work with one click. Works on the second click.
2. I want to make the layout disappear if I touch anywhere other than the layout on top.
   (Of course, the VideoView at the rear should not work when clicked.)
3. If I click EditText, I want to place the EditText and the buttons on the soft keyboard.
   (It is now obscured by the softkeyboard.)

this is my code.

**Java code**

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void onCreate(){

  ...

videoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(videoView.isPlaying()){      
                    videoView.pause();
                    playimg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{                          
                    videoView.start();
                    playimg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

...

comm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(!CommShown()){

                    Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(PlayActivity.this,R.anim.bottom_up);
                    comm_layout.startAnimation(bottomUp);
                    comm_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewGroup.setEnabled(false);
                    //enableDisableViewGroup(viewGroup, false);
                }


            }
        });


        comm_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(CommShown()){
                        Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(PlayActivity.this,R.anim.bottom_down);
                        comm_layout.startAnimation(bottomUp);
                        comm_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    enableDisableViewGroup(viewGroup, true);
                }
            }
        });

} // onCreate


    //comm Visible or Invisivle check

    private boolean CommShown() {
        return comm_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }

    //Comm Open and disable rear view
    public static void enableDisableViewGroup(ViewGroup viewGroup, boolean enabled) {
        int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {


            View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            view.setEnabled(enabled);

            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                enableDisableViewGroup((ViewGroup) view, enabled);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

**xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playimg"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/comm"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comm_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/comm_close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="430dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="comment" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**anim**

```
bottom_up.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>


bottom_down.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="70%p"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

I am sorry that I am not good at English. 
And thank you for your help.

Comment: could you explain you problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sliding a layout up from the bottom of the screen, you can use [BottomSheet](https://www.journaldev.com/13086/android-bottom-sheet) provided by Android.

And for keyboard hiding edit text in the bottom layout, you can check out this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625365/keyboard-hides-bottomsheetdialogfragment/50948146#50948146)

I hope it helps!