# How to use Window#setDecorFitsSystemWindows(boolean) to replace deprecated SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE?

Tags: android, kotlin

Currently, I have a piece of code which is used to resolve issue mentioned in [Keyboard hides BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625365/keyboard-hides-bottomsheetdialogfragment)

```
import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.WindowManager
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment
import com.yocto.wetodo.databinding.TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding

class TodoInputDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private var _binding: TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        return root
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

        dialog.window?.also {
            it.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
        }

        return dialog
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Based on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE, `WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` is deprecated.

We should use `Window#setDecorFitsSystemWindows(boolean)`. But, it isn't clear how we should apply `Window#setDecorFitsSystemWindows(boolean)` for the above case.

Do you have any idea how we should use `Window#setDecorFitsSystemWindows(boolean)` for the above case?